# Error in fastcgi-mono-server4 configuration (webapp) file when specifying multiple sites

Tags: fastcgi-mono-server

I'm trying to start my fastcgi-mono-server4 using a webapp file ,

this is the file located at /etc/rc.d/init.d/mono-fastcgi/servers.webapp

```
<apps>
<web-application>
    <name>api</name>
    <vhost>abc.com/vhost>
    <vport>80</vport>
    <vpath>/</vpath>
    <path>/var/www/abc.com/html</path>
</web-application>
<web-application>
    <name>www</name>
    <vhost>def.com</vhost>
    <vport>80</vport>
    <vpath>/</vpath>
    <path>/var/www/def.com/html</path>
</web-application>
</apps>
```

When I run

```
fastcgi-mono-server4 --appconfigdir=/etc/rc.d/init.d/mono-fastcgi /socket=tcp:127.0.0.1:9000 /printlog=true &
```

This is the exception I get when running

Unhandled Exception:
System.Xml.XmlException: 'vhost' is expected file:///etc/rc.d/init.d/mono-fastcgi/servers.webapp Line 9, position 4.
  at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.Expect (System.String expected) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.ReadEndTag () [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.ReadContent () [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.Read () [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read () [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.Xml.EntityResolvingXmlReader.Read () [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.Xml.Schema.XsdValidatingReader.Read () [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Xml.XmlValidatingReader.Read () [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Xml.XmlDocument.ReadNodeCore (System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Xml.XmlDocument.ReadNodeCore (System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Xml.XmlDocument.ReadNodeCore (System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Xml.XmlDocument.ReadNodeCore (System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Xml.XmlDocument.ReadNode (System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load (System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load (System.String filename) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer.AddApplicationsFromConfigFile (System.String fileName) [0x00000] in :0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Xml.XmlException: 'vhost' is expected file:///etc/rc.d/init.d/mono-fastcgi/servers.webapp Line 9, position 4.
  at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.Expect (System.String expected) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.ReadEndTag () [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.ReadContent () [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.Read () [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read () [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.Xml.EntityResolvingXmlReader.Read () [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.Xml.Schema.XsdValidatingReader.Read () [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Xml.XmlValidatingReader.Read () [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Xml.XmlDocument.ReadNodeCore (System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Xml.XmlDocument.ReadNodeCore (System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Xml.XmlDocument.ReadNodeCore (System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Xml.XmlDocument.ReadNodeCore (System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Xml.XmlDocument.ReadNode (System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load (System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load (System.String filename) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer.AddApplicationsFromConfigFile (System.String fileName) [0x00000] in :0

anyone have any ideas?

cheers!

Comment: Yep another own goal, malformed xml.... time to update that prescription